# Multiplying Gradients in Vector Calculus

Tags: vector-analysis

What happens when you multiply two gradients of two scalar fields together? So:
$$
\vec{\nabla}A\cdot\vec{\nabla}B
$$
Using Einstein summation convention I get:
$$
(\hat{e}_{i}\partial_{i}A)\cdot(\hat{e}_{j}\partial_{j}B) = (\hat{e}_{i}\cdot\hat{e}_{j})(\partial_{i}A\partial_{j}B)=\delta_{ij}(\partial_{i}A\partial_{j}B)=\partial_{i}A\partial_{i}B
$$
Which is correct. But in my notes it says that this also equals:
$$
\vec{\nabla}A\cdot\vec{\nabla}B=\frac{1}{2}(\nabla^2(AB)-A\nabla^2B-B\nabla^2A)
$$
How can this be?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the product rule:

$$
\nabla (AB)= B \nabla A + A\nabla B
$$

Then apply the product rule again.